# Is it possible to store ASCII control characters in a string?

Tags: c++, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm working on a Caesar Shift Cipher for my school assignment and am having trouble implementing the ASCII wrap around functionality. The problem is when the shift occurs outsize of the ASCII range [0, 127]. I currently % the result of the shift by 128 which essentially wraps around the ASCII table. However, values 0-31 are control characters and are not being stored correctly in the string. This prevents me from being able to decrypt the string. Is there a specific data structure that I should use to preserve all of the characters in the ASCII table?

Here is my code:

```
std::string shift(const std::string& str) {
    int shift_pos = 9;
    char original_str[str.length()];
    char encrypted_str[str.length()];
    std::strcpy(original_str, str.c_str());
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        encrypted_str[i] = (original_str[i] + shift_pos) % 128;
    }
    return encrypted_str;
}
```

Comment: Why `QTString` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: I'd expect to see `% 26` somewhere in here, not `% 128`.

Comment: @tadman because it's a requirement of the assignment. The reason why its 128 is because there are 128 values in the ascii table, so if the value exceeds the ascii range by 3, then that value should be encoded as the STX char as that is the 3rd value in the ascii table.

Comment: Hint: It's not 128. That number has absolutely nothing to do with a Caesar Cipher which has existed for a long time before 7-bit ASCII. How many letters are there?

Comment: Well what if the string contains non-alphanumeric characters like '@$%'?

Comment: They normally don't get touched by the cipher. If you wrap around blindly you're going to map things to control characters, newlines, tabs, even a NUL character, which is not what you want.

Comment: ohh i see, so the problem is that I'm trying to represent the control characters, NUL characters, etc. as a string? That's why I'm losing some data?

Comment: You need to specify what your definition of Caesar Cipher is in this particular case. What should the output be? For `tuvwxyz` I'd expect the output to be `cdeghi` given an offset of 9. If you make this function a little bit smarter it could actually handle negative offsets as well, so you could decrypt with it just the same. `shift(x, -9)`.

Comment: @CobraPi ASCII is a 7-bit charset, so it only contains 128 characters. Codepoints > 127 are extended ASCII

Comment: @phuclv because I % the result by 128, shouldn't it wrap around (ex. 130 = 2)?

Comment: I've rolled back your change form `strcpy` to `memcpy`, because it makes the answer confusing. The answer addresses the original question, not one where you fix it based on the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs in your code:

```
std::strcpy(original_str, str.c_str());
```

The `strcpy` function is for C-style strings. Use `memcpy` here.

```
return encrypted_str;
```

How is the constructor for `std::string` invoked by this `return` statement supposed to know how long the string is? The `std::string` constructor that takes a `char *` is only for C-style strings. Call the constructor explicitly and pass the length to it.

If you fix those two issues, your strings should be able to properly handle any kind of arbitrary junk you want to store in them. Don't use any functions meant for C-style strings with arbitrary data.